# Determine a localization of a quotient of a polynomial ring with geometric interpretation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I try to show the following: The only point of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$ with a nonreduced stalk is the origin.

The points in $\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$ are $(y),(x-a,y)$ for $a\in k$. The localization  $\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)_{(y)}=0$ is reduced. 
But I don't know how to determine the localization at $(x-a,y)$.

How can I determine what the localization $\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)_{(x-a,y)}$ is isomorphic to? I'm not sure in general how to determine a localization.

Here is an example using geometric interpretation: $\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(xy)$ is the union of two axes in the plane. Localizing at $x$ means throwing out the locus where $x$ vanishes, so one expects  $(\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(xy))_{(x)}\cong\operatorname{Spec}k[x]_x$. Using this example, $\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$ is the $x$-axis and localizing at $y$ is to throw away $x$ axis, so it's $0$. But I'm not sure how to deal with other cases. If I write $k[x,y]/(y^2,xy))_{(x-a,y)}=\{ \frac{f(x)+ay}{g(x)+by}: g(a)\neq 0\} $, then how can I proceed to determin this localization?

Comment: Why do you believe that localizing $k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$ at the ideal $(x-a,y)$ gives you back $k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$? The localization of a ring at a prime ideal is a local ring, but $k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$ is not local. I would look up the definition of localizing at a prime ideal and try again.

Comment: If I write $k[x,y]/(y^2,xy))_{(x-a,y)}=\{ \frac{f(x)+ay}{g(x)+by}: g(a)\neq 0\} $, then I don't know how to proceed. I always don't know how to see what a localization is isomorphic to. I have seen some example using geometric interpretation to quickly determine the localization. I can say spec$k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$ ``is'' the $y$-axis, localizing at $(y)$ is to throw away $y$-axis, so this localization is $0$. But I don't know how to deal with other cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there's two different types of localizations: we can localize at an element, which means throwing out the vanishing locus of that element, or we can also localize at a prime ideal, which means looking "in a small neighborhood" of that prime ideal. They're very different, and your example in your final paragraph is of the first kind (and has some issues - you want to write $\operatorname{Spec} (k[x,y]/(xy))_x \cong \operatorname{Spec} k[x]_x$ but you appear to have made a typo or two) while you're trying to compute with the second kind in your problem.

Let's recall the definitions of localization. For a multiplicatively closed set $S$ of a ring $A$, we define the localization $S^{-1}A$ to be the ring of fractions $\frac{a}{s}$ with $a\in A$ and $s\in S$ with the usual addition and subtraction, where two fractions $\frac{a}{s}$ and $\frac{a'}{s'}$ are equal iff there is some $u\in S$ with $u(as'-a's)=0$. Localization at an element corresponds to setting $S=\{1,f,f^2,\cdots\}$, where localization at a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ corresponds to setting $S=A\setminus\mathfrak{p}$.

In order to solve the problem, recall that localization is exact, so it commutes with quotients: $$(k[x,y]/(y^2,xy))_{(x-a,y)} \cong k[x,y]_{(x-a,y)}/(y^2,xy)_{(x-a,y)}.$$ Next, note that $a\neq 0$ is equivalent to $x\notin (x-a,y)$, so $x$ is invertible in this localization iff $a\neq 0$. When $x$ is invertible, then $(y^2,xy)=(y)$, and the quotient is just $k[x,y]_{(x-a,y)}/(y)_{(x-a,y)}\cong (k[x,y]/(y))_{(x-a,y)}\cong k[x]_{(x-a)}$ which is clearly reduced. When $a=0$, $x$ isn't invertible, and $y\neq 0$ but $y^2=0$ which means the ring $(k[x,y]/(y^2,xy))_{(x,y)}$ has nilpotents and isn't reduced.

Comment: What does ``looking in a small neighborhood'' mean?

Comment: For the stalk at $(y)$, it is $k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)_{(y)}= k[x,y]_{(y)}/(xy,y^2)_{(y)}=k[x,y]_{(y)}/(y)=(k[x,y]/(y))_{(y)}=0$, right?

Comment: 1) It's more of a general idea - the localization at a prime ideal is smaller than any open set containing that prime ideal, but still big enough to remember most information which is associated to any open set containing the point. 2) To compute the stalk at $(y)$, your're off to a good start - the term $(k[x,y]/(y))_{(y)}$ is correct, but the conclusion it's zero is not. Remember what localizing at $(y)$ means: we invert every element not in $(y)$. But this means any polynomial in $x$ is inverted, so $k[x,y]/(y)_{(y)} = k[x]_{(0)} = k(x)$ which is what you would expect at the generic point

Comment: ... because the two varieties $k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$ and $k[x]$ are birational to each other - the open sets $D(x)$ inside both are isomorphic, and the stalk of the structure sheaf at the generic point of two irreducible birational varieties is the same.

Comment: This argument is assuming $k$ is algebraically closed, right? Otherwise, there would be other prime ideals as well?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Yes, I suppose so - it's been more than a year since I wrote this post, so I can't remember exactly what I was thinking when I wrote it, but I suppose that when the OP said that "the points ... are $(y)$ and $(x-a,y)$" that I took this as an assumption that $k$ is algebraically closed. Removing this assumption is easy, though - if $k$ is not algebraically closed, then the points are of the form $(y)$ or $(m(x),y)$ for $m$ irreducible over $k$, and $m(x)\neq x$ is equivalent to $x\notin (m(x),y)$, so one need only find/replace "$x-a$" to "$m(x)$".

Comment: @KReiser: Ah, okay. Incidentally, it was this post that had led to the mistake in my post from earlier today! On thinking about it more, I came up with another solution that does not require us to explicitly work out the localisation, which I've posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A$ can have other prime ideals, if $k$ is not algebraically closed.
However, after noting that $A_x \cong k[x]_x$, the problem is simple.

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $A$ and $S = A \setminus \mathfrak{p}.$ We wish to show that $A_{\mathfrak{p}} = S^{-1}A$ is nonreduced iff $\mathfrak{p} = (x, y).$

Now, we know that $A_x$ is an integral domain. Thus, if $x \in S,$ then $S^{-1}A$ is also domain, being a further localisation of $A_x.$ (Obviously, $0 \notin S.$)

Thus, if $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is nonreduced, then $x \in \mathfrak{p}.$ Moreover, since $y$ is nilpotent in $A,$ $y \in \mathfrak{p}$ as well. Thus, $(x, y) \subset \mathfrak{p}.$ Maximality of $(x, y)$ now forces $\mathfrak{p} = (x, y).$

---

Now, either you can show that $A_{(x, y)}$ is indeed nonreduced by hand or use the fact that since $A$ is not reduced, one of its stalks must necessarily be nonreduced.